# Put object on Google Maps from database

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to inform you that this is my first time doing this so I am completely in the dark. I would love some input.
I want to map an object on Google maps with its place given. For Ex:- Downtown, Los Angeles, USA. I have a  database where these locations and objects are stored and I want to show that on Google maps.I do not have the longitudes and latitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load a address in google maps, You have to use server side Geocoding service API(since you have asked to load it from database).

**Server Side**

**Geocoding Service API**

Which will help you to change the address into lattitude and longitude.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Once if you have got the Lattitude and Longtitude at the runtime (server side). Then [construct a KML file](http://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak/quickstart.html)(I have given a Java example, If you are using [PHP](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml)) which will help you to render at the client side.

**Client Side**

You need one more library to render at the Client side Google Maps. That is geoxml. For your
 to parse the KML file [Reference](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I did something similar but ...

I have places stored in my Database and I do not have longitudes/latitudes. So i calculate them at run-time from the google api's

I have used this KML file for this and the following mentioned library.

https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage

You have to use your database to build a KML file then place that KML file from some accessible location and use the Geoxml KML processor of the above link
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank You! I will try that and get back to you.